# How to add previous value to next href in foreach loop codeigniter breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, breadcrumbs

I am using codeigniter breadcrumbs.

Here is my breadcrumb showing in my view:

```
Home >> rd-sharma-solutions >> class-12 >> chapter-22-differential-equations >> exercise-22-10
```

When I click on Home it redirecting me to `Home` but when I click on `rd-sharma-solutions` or `class-12` it is also redirecting me to Home page url.

What I am using is foreach loop to add the links:

Here is my `Controller` code:

```
$uri_data = $this->uri->segment_array();
unset($uri_data[2]);
unset($uri_data[1]);
$this->mybreadcrumb->add('Home', base_url());
foreach ($uri_data as $key) {
    $this->mybreadcrumb->add($key, base_url($key));
    // I want to add the $key value next time in base_url($key. '/' . $key);
}
```

Here is my `url`:

```
http://localhost:8080/courses/Book/solution/rd-sharma-solutions/class-12/chapter-22-differential-equations/exercise-22-10/
```

I want to append the previous url value next time so that I can add it to my breadcrumb href.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. my it will help you

```
$uri_data = $this->uri->segment_array();
        $breadcrumbs = array();
        for ($i=count($uri_data); $i > 2 ; $i--) { 
            if ($i == count($uri_data)) {
                $breadcrumbs[] =  "recent link"; // for your recent breadcrumb // do ur html
            } else {
            $breadcrumbs[] = $uri_data[$i]; // loop you downword // do ur html 
            }
        }
            krsort($breadcrumbs); // sort your array
            foreach ($breadcrumbs as $value) {
                echo $value;
            }
```